# When to pronounce long u as "yoo" or "ooo"

Tags: pronunciation

Can you look at a word and see if a "u" should be pronounced as "ooo" or "yoo" by using some set of rules, or do you just have to know the correct pronunciation ahead of time?

For example:

```
cop[u]late "yoo"
l[u]minate "ooo"
r[u]minate "ooo"
imm[u]ne "yoo"
cons[u]me  "ooo"
comm[u]ne "yoo"
```

Comment: I pronounce consume with a yoo sound.

Comment: New York drops its yod half way across the Atlantic (travelling westwards).

Comment: Not only isn't there a rule, there isn't even agreement.

Comment: You might want to include t[u]ne “yoo” in British English (at least some forms), which sounds strange to this American ear.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following are reasonable guidelines (although there are numerous exceptions, like *cuckoo*).

For words that came from Middle English, in standard British English you pronounce long u as "oo" if it follows an "l", "r", "sh", "ch", or "j" sound; and "yoo" otherwise.

In standard American, you can pronounce long u as "oo" if it follows an "l", "r", "sh" "ch", "j", "n", "t", "d", "s", "z" or "th" sound; and "yoo" otherwise.

This phenomenon is called "yod dropping" and exactly what consonants trigger it varies widely with the specific dialect of English (and maybe even the speaker). 
[See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Y-cluster_reductions).

For foreign words, like *kudos*, *sushi*, and *puma*, all bets are off. All of these were pronounced "oo" in their original languages, but English speakers may (fairly randomly) decide to pronounce some of them with the spelling pronunciation.

Comment: Great info! And knowing its called yod dropping is also helpful.

Comment: Yep. Syllable structure/word stress also affects yod-dropping: compare menu and renew or value and allure.

Comment: I can imagine someone saying _pyuma_. I can just about accept _kyudos_. But _syushi_?!? Surely not! @sumelic _Allure_ is an interesting case since it’s pronounced both with and without yod on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Also, how is _cuckoo_ an exception? The u is /ɵ/, and the only /uː/ in the word is _oo_ (= from a pre-Great Vowel Shift /oː/) and never had a yod to drop.

Comment: @Janus: Nobody says *syushi*. I was including it to show that sometimes people add an extraneous yod and sometimes they don't. (The only pronunciations in some British dictionaries are *kyudos* and *pyuma* —  although *kyudos* sounds horrible to me, since it's usually yodless in the U.S.) And *cuckoo* is an exception only if you use the most common American pronunciation, which has two  /uː/s.

Comment: @PeterShor Oh thank god. _Syushi_ would just about have destroyed my faith in the English-speaking part of humanity. (And both _pyuma_ and _kyudos_ sound terrible to me as well, dictionaries be damned. But then, the typical American _kudose_ [ˈkuːˌdoʊs/z] sounds dreadful to me as well…)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Actually, "cuckoo" seems to be a relatively recent borrowing from French, and it was not affected by the Great Vowel shift -- it never had /oː/, the "oo" spelling is just to represent the sound /uː/.

Comment: @sumelic: *Cuckoo* goes back to 1240, so it should have been affected by the Great Vowel shift. And it had various spellings, probably representing various vowels, including /oː/, in Middle English (among the ones the OED gives are *cuccu, koko, kookoo*). The fact that it was imitative probably helped it to resist the Great Vowel shift to some extent – for example, I can't imagine it being pronounced *cowcow*, which would be the shift from the original French pronunciation /kuːkuː/.

Answer (score 0):

Whether u says /oo/ or /yoo/ is determined by whether or not the preceeding consonant is voiced (vibrates the voice box) or unvoiced.

Some guidelines for when ‘u’ says /oo/ or /yoo/ are:
It usually says /oo/ when it follows a voiced consonant (g, j, l, y, s, r, z).
It usually says /yoo/ when it follows an unvoiced consonant (b, d, p, c, f, h, t).

As languages evolve both in pronunciation and dialect, this 'rule' is weakened somewhat, however it does still hold true in the majority of cases.

Learn a rule and figure out exceptions through exposure is what I always say.

Comment: In your second list, b and d are voiced, not unvoiced. Maybe you should give a good list of examples and pronunciations to confirm your rules.